# What is the difference between \dfrac and \frac?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

The title says it all, both `\dfrac{a}{b}` and `\frac{a}{b}` make fractions, so what is the difference between the two?

Comment: displayed frac.

Comment: This is clearly mentioned in the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) (section **4.11.1 The `\frac`, `\dfrac`, and `\tfrac` commands**, p 14).

Comment: Here's the current, working link to a home for the [`amsmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath?lang=en) package and [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf).

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Mainly it's a difference of size:

- `\dfrac` means that the fraction is set in **d**isplaystyle
- `\tfrac` means that the fraction is set in **t**extstyle
- with `\frac`: the actual context implies the decision above

For example, if you have a complicated mathematical expression in the middle of some `array` environment (which, by default, employs text-style math), you can use `\dfrac` to force the use of displaystyle math mode for the fraction

`\dfrac` and `\tfrac` are from the `amsmath` package

Aside: TeX provides four math "styles": display style, text style, script style, and scriptscript style. scriptstyle is generally meant for level-1 subscripts and superscripts, and scriptscriptstyle is for level-2 subscripts and superscripts.

Answer (score 132):

`\dfrac` forces the fraction into display mode, no matter which mode it is in already. On the other hand `\tfrac` forces it to be in text mode.

Usually `\tfrac` is used much more than `\dfrac`. Of course `\frac` should be used in almost every case but `\tfrac` is handy for coefficients, as shown by the code below.

```
\[
   f(x) =  \frac{1}{2} x^2 = \dfrac{1}{2} x^2 = \tfrac{1}{2} x^2
\]
```

[image]

```
$
   f(x) =  \frac{1}{2} x^2 = \dfrac{1}{2} x^2 = \tfrac{1}{2} x^2
$
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Though I am responding late, The answer specific to the question is by masu and daleif. This is a piece of supplement information to the question.
One has to use the package xfrac to use sfrac.

```
\usepackage{xfrac}

$

f(x) = (\sfrac{1}{2})x^2

$
```

[image]

Comment: The question here is about `\dfrac` and `\frac`, not `\sfrac` from [`xfrac`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfrac), unfortunately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).