# Sum within a fraction

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to get a sum to display "properly" within a fraction. My input is:

```
\begin{equation}
    E = 1 - \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(O_{i}-P_{i})^{2}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(O_{i}-\bar{O})^{2}}
\end{equation}
```

And the output looks like this: [image]

I want the indices to appear above and below the sum as opposed to the side. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: This is the proper way, in order to save some vertical space.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `\limits` just before `_` and `^` in connection with `\sum` command, the same holds also for an integral `\int\limits^{b}_{a}` for example.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{book}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    E = 1 - \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(O_{i}-P_{i})^{2}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(O_{i}-\bar{O})^{2}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But shouldn't `\dfrac` make both numerator and denominator in `\displaystyle` mode?

Comment: @Manuel: Yes, that is true, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135389/what-is-the-difference-between-dfrac-and-frac, but as far as I know \displaystyle mode has no effect on the positioning of limits of sum or integral symbols

Comment: No, in fact it doesn't have to make both of them `\displaystyle`. If I'm not mistaken it just makes the whole fraction `\displaystyle` (therefore, the two parts are `\textstyle`).

Comment: There is no need for `\dfrac`; here, `\frac` suffice.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: I just used it from the 'MWE' above