# lfloor and rfloor dipping down too far

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

Why is the right-hand side delimiters going much further down than the depth of the denominator?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
  \left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^{i+1}} \right \rfloor = 
    \left \lfloor \dfrac{\left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^i} \right \rfloor}{p} \right \rfloor
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\left \lfloor \frac{n}{p^{i+1}} \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor \frac{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{p^i} \right \rfloor}{p} \right \rfloor$
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Q.v.* [What is the Difference Between `\dfrac` and `\frac`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135389/what-is-the-difference-between-dfrac-and-frac)