# how do I number equations in multiple columns?

Tags: equations, align, numbering

I am new to LaTeX, but recently started making worksheets for my students to assign as homework. I want to left align multiple equations in more than one column and I want them to be automatically numbered with the number being on the left like in the picture below.
[image: image of 6 equations written in 2 columns, each equation is labeled with a letter]

So far I have only figured out how to align the equations and manually put labels next to them but would very much like to make it automatic if possible.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\text{a) }4x+7=3x-13 &\text{d) }&\frac{9-27x}{3}-0.75(\frac{1}{3}x-8)+0.25x=-9(x-1)\\
&\text{b) }6-x-3(2-x)=12+8x &\text{e) }& 8x(1-x)-5(4x-2)+18=8(x+1)(1-x)\\
&\text{c) }\frac{6-4x}{3}=\frac{7x+9}{4}-2 &\text{f) }& -37+0.4(10-5x)-\frac{10-30x}{10}=x
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using enumerate and multicol packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Don't forget this one !
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a)]
        \item $4x+7=3x-13 $
        \item $\frac{9-27x}{3}-0.75(\frac{1}{3}x-8)+0.25x=-9(x-1)$
        \item $6-x-3(2-x)=12+8x$
        \item $8x(1-x)-5(4x-2)+18=8(x+1)(1-x)$
        \item $\frac{6-4x}{3}=\frac{7x+9}{4}-2 $
        \item $-37+0.4(10-5x)-\frac{10-30x}{10}=x$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add as many columns as you want and it split automatically. `:)`

Comment: This works for what I am making now but only allows a line length of 1 for equations so the fractions look a bit compressed and can be hard to read

Comment: @daridaUdens You may use ``\dfrac`` instead of ``\frac``. Or use the package ``enumitem`` instead of ``enumerate`` (enumitem supercedes enumerate anyway). Then you may try things like ``\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*),before=\everymath{\displaystyle}]`` instead of ``\begin{enumerate}[a)]``. Or you could add ``\displaystyle`` on the specific lines you need it, after ``\item``, and so on.

Comment: See this post to know more about `\frac\dfrac\tfrac` https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135389/what-is-the-difference-between-dfrac-and-frac/135392